# Remove 'SMTP' from 'SMTP:email@domain.com' in PowerShell using Get-AzureADUser

Tags: powershell, email, scripting, smtp, azure-active-directory

I am using the below script to display aliases for users in O365 which I will eventually be exporting.

```
Get-AzureADUser |
    Select-Object @(
        @{L = "Name"; E = { $_.DisplayName}}
        @{L = "Email"; E = { $_.UserPrincipalName}}
        @{L = "Aliases"; E = { $_.ProxyAddresses -join ";"}}
    )
```

In the Aliases (`ProxyAddresses`) column, it displays all the aliases separated by a `;` as expected but it also includes `SMTP:` in front of all of them.

Is there a way to remove the `SMTP:` from these values?

*Current result*: `SMTP:email@domain.com;SMTP:email2@domain.com`

*Desired result*: `email@domain.com;email2@domain.com`

Comment: put `-replace 'smtp:'` in front of `-join`

Comment: `-replace 'SMTP: ',''`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
Get-AzureADUser |
    Select-Object @(
        @{L = "Name"; E = { $_.DisplayName}}
        @{L = "Email"; E = { $_.UserPrincipalName}}
        @{L = "Aliases"; E = { $_.ProxyAddresses -replace '^smtp:' -join ';' }}
    )
```

This will replace `smtp:` at the beginning (`^`) of each proxyaddress, using PowerShell's ability to make operators automatically work on all members of an array, then join the results.

Comment: Thank you. I also want to remove cloud emails from my list of aliases.

Current Result: email@domain.com;email2@domain.com;email3@domain.onmicrosoft.com

Desired result:
email@domain.com;email2@domain.com

I would like to remove any email from the array that contains ".onmicrosoft.com".

Answer (score 0):

If you also want to lose the ".onmicrosoft.com" addresses this should work

```
Get-AzureADUser |
    Select-Object @(
        @{L = "Name"; E = { $_.DisplayName}}
        @{L = "Email"; E = { $_.UserPrincipalName}}
        @{L = "Aliases"; E = { 
            $proxies = $_.ProxyAddresses -replace '^smtp:'
            $proxies = $proxies | Where-Object { $_ -notlike '*.onmicrosoft.com' }
            $proxies -join '; ' }
        }
    )
```

Mind you, the `ProxyAddresses` attribute can also hold other entries like `SIP:upn@domain.com` or `X500: /o=company/ou=External (FYDIBOHF25SPDLT)/cn=Recipients/cn=userxxx`

If you also would like to exclude those, use

```
Get-AzureADUser |
    Select-Object @(
        @{L = "Name"; E = { $_.DisplayName}}
        @{L = "Email"; E = { $_.UserPrincipalName}}
        @{L = "Aliases"; E = { 
            $proxies = $_.ProxyAddresses
            $proxies = $proxies | Where-Object { $_ -match '^smtp:' -and $_ -notlike '*.onmicrosoft.com' }
            $proxies -replace '^smtp:' -join '; ' }
        }
    )
```