# Remove full email with specific domain in PowerShell using Get-AzureADUser

Tags: powershell, email, scripting, azure-active-directory

I am currently using the below script.

```
 Get-AzureADUser |
    Select-Object @(
        @{L = "Name"; E = { $_.DisplayName}}
        @{L = "Email"; E = { $_.UserPrincipalName}}
        @{L = "Aliases"; E = { $_.ProxyAddresses -replace '^smtp:' -join ';' }}
    )
```

Most of my results return an email address in the array similar to `email@domain.onmicrosoft.com`. I need these emails to be removed from the array in the Aliases (ProxyAdresses) field. Essentially, any email containing `onmicrosoft.com` needs to be removed.

Current result: `email1@domain.com;email2@domain.com;email3@domain.onmicrosoft.com`

Desired result: `email1@domain.com;email2@domain.com`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Remove 'SMTP' from 'SMTP:email@domain.com' in PowerShell using Get-AzureADUser](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51503708/remove-smtp-from-smtpemaildomain-com-in-powershell-using-get-azureaduser)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can chain another operator on there, to work as a filter:

```
Get-AzureADUser |
    Select-Object @(
        @{L = "Name"; E = { $_.DisplayName}}
        @{L = "Email"; E = { $_.UserPrincipalName}}
        @{L = "Aliases"; E = { $_.ProxyAddresses -notlike '*onmicrosoft*' -replace '^smtp:' -join ';' }}
    )
```

but it's getting increasingly difficult to read now. Note that the expression is a full scriptblock, so you can break it out over multiple lines and write things more clearly, e.g.:

```
Get-AzureADUser |
    Select-Object @(
        @{L = "Name"; E = { $_.DisplayName}}
        @{L = "Email"; E = { $_.UserPrincipalName}}
        @{L = "Aliases"; E = { 

            $filteredMails = $_.ProxyAddresses | Where-Object { 
                $_ -notlike '*onmicrosoft*'
            }

            $filteredMails = $filteredMails -replace '^smtp:'

            $filteredMails -join ';' 

        }}
    )
```

Comment: This question has already been asked and answered. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51503708/remove-smtp-from-smtpemaildomain-com-in-powershell-using-get-azureaduser

Comment: @Theo They asked one question, I answered it, and they accepted my answer. After that, they extended/changed their question in a comment, which is bad StackOverflow etiquette. A different question should really be a different question on StackOverflow. That aside, why are you commenting on my answer? About the only things that would make sense, are you to ask the questioner to change their accepted answer on the other question, and for you to flag this question as a duplicate, or flag for moderator attention somehow. There isn't much I can do, except maybe delete my answer here, to no benefit

Comment: Sorry, I commented in the wrong place. It was about the question, not your answer. Later I flagged as duplicate.